# How to make a derived class use a property of a base class?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, linq-to-sql, expression

The general idea starts from creating a control, which would work with any database object.
The database is accessed via LINQ to SQL, and database objects are auto-generated from the existing database.

To make the control work with any of these objects, I use a base interface, which all the auto-generated objects inherit from. So the control actually works with that interface.

This interface at first should provide:

1. an ability to get the identifier (primary key) of an object
2. an expression which would return this identifier, if compiled and called via an instance of an object

So this looks like:

```
public interface IEntity<TEntity, TEntityId>
    where TEntity : IEntity<TEntity, TEntityId>
    where TEntityId : IEquatable<TEntityId>
{
    Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntityId>> GetIdExpression();
    TEntityId EntityId { get; }
}
```

Then a database object's class definition would look like:

```
//let it be the auto-generated part:
public partial class Entity1
{
    public Guid UId { get; set; }
}
//and the manual part:
public partial class Entity1 : IEntity<Entity1, Guid>
{
    public Expression<Func<Entity1, Guid>> GetIdExpression()
    {
        return (Expression<Func<Entity1, Guid>>)(se => se.UId);
    }
    public Guid EntityId
    {
        get { return this.UId; }
    }
}
```

And we can test it:

```
var e1 = new Entity1();
e1.UId = Guid.NewGuid();
Console.WriteLine(e1.UId); 
Console.WriteLine(e1.GetIdExpression().Compile()(e1));
```

The output of these two lines is equal. It's OK.

The next idea was, that the lion share of all database objects have `int` identifier with the name `Id`. And it would be much better to avoid editing every of them, i.e. not to write one and the same code implementing `IEntity<TEntity, TEntityId>`.

As far as I need to specify the implementation of this interface, I need a class.
For now I ended up with

```
public class IntEntity<TEntity> : IEntity<TEntity, int>
       where TEntity : IntEntity<TEntity>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Expression<Func<TEntity, int>> GetIdExpression()
    {
        return (Expression<Func<TEntity, int>>)(e => e.Id);
    }

    public int EntityId
    {
        get { return this.Id; }
    }
}
```

Then the database object class would derive from it:

```
//let it be the auto-generated part:
public partial class Entity2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
//and the manual part:
public partial class Entity2 : IntEntity<Entity2>
{
}
```

Already now it's obvious, that `Id` in `Entity2` does hide the `Id` in `IntEntity<TEntity>`. This is also proved by the same test:

```
var re = new Entity2();
re.Id = 5;
Console.WriteLine(re.Id); //5
Console.WriteLine(re.GetIdExpression().Compile()(re)); //0
```

So this solution is wrong...
I also tryed to make `IntEntity<TEntity>` abstract, but obviously failed, as in `Entity2` `Id` is defined in the auto-generated part, and I could not make it `override` the `abstract` `Id` of the base class.

Is there anything I can do to make all database objects with `int Id` use the `Id` from the base `IntEntity<TEntity>` class. Or, probably, vice versa...

The main point here is that the expression returned by `GetIdExpression` should have the form `e => e.Id`, as this expresion would later be used in LINQ to SQL queries, so LINQ should be able to translate it to a correct SQL query.

Comment: so why you need `id` property in `Entity2` and `IntEntity<Entity2>` rather than only one of them?

Comment: as variant for solve - add to `Id` in `IntEntity<Entity2>` keyword `virtual` and to `Id` in `Entity2` `override`

Comment: @Grundy `Id` in `Entity2` is auto-generated by LINQ to SQL. I cannot modify it's declaration.

Comment: @Grundy in `IntEntity<Entity2>` I need `Id` to be able to provide the implementation of the `IEntity<TEntity, int>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's exactly what you want, but you can try to do so

```
public abstract class IntEntity<TEntity> : IEntity<TEntity, int>
   where TEntity : IntEntity<TEntity>
{
    public abstract Expression<Func<TEntity, int>> GetIdExpression();
    public abstract int EntityId
    {
        get;
    }
}

public partial class Entity2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
//and the manual part:
public partial class Entity2 : IntEntity<Entity2>
{
    public override int EntityId
    {
        get { return this.Id; }
    }

    public override Expression<Func<Entity2, int>> GetIdExpression()
    {
        return (Expression<Func<TEntity, int>>)(e => e.Id);
    }
}
```

in fact without `override` `virtual` you can't get access to field in derive class from method in base class
in sample above in fact equals your first sample

**UPDATE**

as workaround you can add method SetId that set id in derive and base class like this

```
public class IntEntity<TEntity> : IEntity<TEntity, int>
   where TEntity : IntEntity<TEntity>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Expression<Func<TEntity, int>> GetIdExpression()
    {
        return (Expression<Func<TEntity, int>>)(e => e.Id);
    }

    public int EntityId
    {
        get { return this.Id; }
    }
}

//let it be the auto-generated part:
public partial class Entity2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
//and the manual part:
public partial class Entity2 : IntEntity<Entity2>
{
    public void SetId(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
        base.Id = id;
    }
}

var re = new Entity2();
re.SetId(5);
Console.WriteLine(re.Id); //5
Console.WriteLine(re.GetIdExpression().Compile()(re)); //5
```

Comment: @horgh what do you mean?

Comment: As the `GetIdExpression` must have form `e => e.Id` only, as in the database there is no `EntityId`, only `Id`...and therefore an expression `e => e.EntityId` would not be parsed by LINQ to SQL

Comment: Now your code suggests overriding abstract members of `IntEntity<TEntity>` in each and every database object. Actually it's the same as my first example with `Entity1`, only instead of implementing `IEntity<TEntity, int>`, it leads to overrides of abstract members. In fact in this version, the `IntEntity<TEntity>` class is absolutely useless.